# Proof verification: $G, H$ are isomorphic graphs if there exists a $P$ such that $A_G = P A_H P^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

I've seen a couple arguments given but not a full proof that two graphs $G, H$ are isomorphic iff there exists a permutation matrix $P$ such that $A_G = P A_H P^T$, so I'd thought I'd write up a formal proof of the forward direction, but I am stuck.

Suppose that $G, H$ are isomorphic and both have $n$ vertices where the vertices of $G$ are labelled $V_G = \{g_{1}, \ldots, g_{n} \}$ and the vertices of $H$ are labelled $\{h_{1}, \ldots , h_{n} \}$. By the definition of an isomorphism there exists a permutation $\sigma$ such that whenever $(g_{i} g_{j})$ is an edge in $G$, that $(h_{\sigma(i)}, h_{\sigma(j)})$ is an edge in $H$.

Let $P$ be a permutation matrix $P$ defined row-wise. The $t$'th row of $P$ will contain all zeros except for the entry at index $\sigma(t)$. Let $A_G, A_H$ be the adjacency matrices of the graphs $G$ and $H$.

If $A_G = PA_HP^T$, then $A_G P = P A_H$ (this is what I want to show).

For $u,v$ with $1 \leq u \leq n$ and $1 \leq v \leq n$:

Then $$(A_G P)_{u,v} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (A_G)_{u,i} P_{i,v} = (A_G)_{u, \sigma^{-1}(v)}$$

and $$(P A_H)_{u,v} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} P_{u,i} (A_H)_{i,v} = (A_H)_{\sigma(u), v}$$

Edit: My attempt to finish the argument is:

Let $t=\sigma^{-1}(v)$. Then as per the definition of an isomorphism, if $(u, t)$ are adjacent in $A_G$, then $(\sigma(u), \sigma (t))$ is adjacent in $A_H$, but $\sigma(t) = v$, hence for all $u,v$, $(A_G P)_{u,v} = (P A_H)_{u,v}$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Why are you computing $PA_G$? You're meant to prove $A_G=PA_HP^t$, that doesn't involve $PA_G$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson editing now to explain my approach/fix errors.